# StanfordNLP : ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for Named Entity Recognition

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to learn NER using [this](https://humphreysheil.blogspot.in/2014/10/named-entity-recognition-short-tutorial.html) short Named Entity Recognition tutorial. But I am unable to run the code successfully. I provided one entry in location.txt file as mentioned there.

I am getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error.

```
09:32:09.431 [main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator regexner

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

at  edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokensRegexNERAnnotator.readEntries(TokensRegexNERAnnotator.java:696)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokensRegexNERAnnotator.readEntries(TokensRegexNERAnnotator.java:593)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokensRegexNERAnnotator.<init>(TokensRegexNERAnnotator.java:294)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.tokensRegexNER(AnnotatorImplementations.java:135)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorFactories$7.create(AnnotatorFactories.java:305)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:152)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:451)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:154)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:150)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:137)
```

Kindly help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example rexegner rule:

```
London    LOCATION    MISC    1
```

Make sure the 4 columns are separated by a "\t" character not spaces.

Comment: I am still getting same error even after putting example regexner rule there in location.txt

Comment: You have to separate the 4 columns by a tab.  If you are getting that error it means your rules are not separated by a tab.

Comment: I put above rule as `chairman of the board "\t" TITLE  "\t" MISC  "\t" 1` in location.text and provided test text as `Chairman of the Board Bienaime Jean-Jacques'. Still I am getting same error.

Comment: yes, error is gone now. I managed to run it with `\\t` for tab in regexner rule file.